# Do you need an API with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app with React and Firebase. So, to interact with the database from the client (React), do I need an API? What are the upsides/downsides of using something like `db.collection("cities").get()` or using an API to make a request to

> firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API provided by the client SDK is easier to consume, and will store documents in a [local cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), so they can be used offline (if you enable it for web apps).  The REST API is harder to use and does nothing to help you cache results on the device.